# Covering space action on a product space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, group-actions, covering-spaces

I am working on the following problem:

Given covering space actions of groups $G_1$ on $X_1$ and $G_2$ on $X_2$, show that the action of $G_1 \times G_2$ on $X_1 \times X_2$ defined by $(g_1,g_2)(x_1,x_2) = (g_1(x_1), g_2(x_2))$ is a covering space action, and that $(X_1 \times X_2)/(G_1 \times G_2)$ is homeomorphic to $X_1/G_1 \times X_2/G_2$.

The following is the definition that I have for a covering space action:

- (1) If $G$ is a group and $X$ is a topological space, then an *action* of $G$ on $X$ is a homomorphism $\phi:G \rightarrow \text{Homeo}(X)$, where $\text{Homeo}(X)$ is the set of all homeomorphisms $X \rightarrow X$. (Each $g \in G$ is associated to a homeomorphism $\phi(g):X \rightarrow X$, but we will write $g:X \rightarrow X$ in place of $\phi(g):X \rightarrow X$.)
- (2) If, in addition, each $x \in X$ has a neighborhood $U$ such that $g_1(U) \cap g_2(U) \neq \emptyset$ implies $g_1 = g_2$ for all $g_1,g_2 \in G$, then the action of $G$ on $X$ is said to be a *covering space action*.

It is easy for me to check that the action of $G_1 \times G_2$ on $X_1 \times X_2$ defined in the problem is indeed an action according to (1), but I'm struggling with showing that it is a covering space action according to (2).

Suppose $(x_1,x_2) \in X_1 \times X_2$, $U_1$ is a neighborhood of $x_1 \in X_1$ that yields the covering space action of $G_1$ on $X_1$ via (2), and $U_2$ is a neighborhood of $x_2 \in X_2$ that yields the covering space action of $G_2$ on $X_2$ via (2). My idea was to consider the neighborhood $U_1 \times U_2$ of $(x_1,x_2)$. I would have to show that, for all $(g_1,g_2),(g_3,g_4) \in G_1 \times G_2$, we have that $(g_1,g_2)(U_1 \times U_2) \cap (g_3,g_4)(U_1 \times U_2) \neq \emptyset$ implies that $(g_1,g_2) = (g_3,g_4)$. How can I go about showing this? From there, how can I go about showing the desired homeomorphism $(X_1 \times X_2)/(G_1 \times G_2) \cong X_1/G_1 \times X_2/G_2$?

Thanks!

Comment: What's stopping you from computing $(g_1,g_2).(U_1\times U_2)\cap(g_3,g_4).(U_1\times U_2)$? Only a couple set-theoretic rearrangements and you have the expression you want.

Comment: @Thorgott Aah, I see. I didn't realize that we only needed set theory for that. What about the homeomorphism $(X_1 \times X_2)/(G_1 \times G_2) \cong X_1/G_1 \times X_2/G_2$, though?

Comment: Are you struggling to come up with a map $(X_1\times X_2)/(G_1\times G_2)\rightarrow X_1/G_1\times X_2/G_2$ or are you struggling with proving it's a homeomorphism?

Comment: @Thorgott Coming up with a map, I suppose.

Comment: Ok, can you come up with a natural map $X_1\times X_2\rightarrow X_1/G_1\times X_2/G_2$?

Comment: @Thorgott I believe we would just take the product of the natural projection map $\pi_1:X_1 \rightarrow X_1/G_1$ and the natural projection map $\pi_2:X_2 \rightarrow X_2/G_2$ there.

Comment: Ok, convince yourself this map is surjective, that it is open and that it factors through an open bijection $(X_1\times X_2)/(G_1\times G_2)\rightarrow X_1/G_1\times X_2/G_2$ by the universal property of the quotient, which is hence a homeomorphism.

Comment: @Thorgott I can get everything except for injectivity from your discussion and the universal property. Any suggestions?

Comment: This should be straightforward from the definition. What point are you getting stuck at?

Comment: @Thorgott Aah, I see. I was overthinking it. Thanks for all of your help. I've finally conquered this problem.